# Why is this ffmpeg command outputting such long clips?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying edit out a two minute clip from a long movie.

This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:05:16 -t 120 -i input.avi -vcodec copy -an clips/output.avi
```

I thought that 120 would be in seconds, giving me a two minute clip. But the clip I get is over 45 minutes long. It seems to be as long as from the start time to the end of the film.

Why is this not working and what command should I use to get a two minute clip?

Comment: ffmpeg is sensitive to the order in which you put the different options. Try changing that around (as Mulvya) suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the time after `-t` has to be in the format `00:00:00`. So, for a two minute clip, the command is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -sameq -ss 01:05:16 -t 00:02:00 clips/output.avi
```

Comment: This is a perfectly fine solution, except you should (almost) never use -sameq - it doesn't mean 'same quality'. There are a few cases where it may be useful, but it is very much an advances option (so if you aren't sure that you need to use it, don't use it).

Comment: And it was removed in recent `ffmpeg` builds - https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f

Answer (score 0):

Try putting`-t 120` after `-an`